# What is the exact relation between prime numbers and the zeta function?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

i would like to know what is the exact relation between prime numbers and the zeta function.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you heard of the Euler product formula?

Comment: see here http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Riffer-Reinert.pdf

Comment: thank you ! i'll check it right now !

Comment: $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is a very simple analytic function but $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{p^k} p^{-sk} \log p$ is very complicated (and chaotic). By inverse Laplace transform we obtain that $|x-\sum_{p^k < x} \log p| < C x^{\sigma} \log^2 x$ iff $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{1}{s-1}$ is analytic (ie. $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros) on $\Re(s) > \sigma$.

Comment: Just as companion of previous comments and reference, I want to add an additional reference from the literature (I am aficionado, but this reference is very good). You can read the nice *The lowest zeros of Riemann's zeta are in front of your eyes* (October 30, 2014), from the blog of professor David Mumford. Good luck, isn't required a response of this comment.